# Efficienly prune invalid branches from hierarchy when given it in a flat array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, hierarchy

I have a flat list of items. Some of the items in the list are parents of other items in the list. I need to go through each item, and make sure it's not invalid. Each item has an expiration time, and an item is invalid if it's own or any of it's parent's expiration times have passed. How can I efficiently remove all invalid items from the list?

Essentially I am given a hierarchical set of data in an array. Each item has it's own id, a parentID, the time information, and other non-useful data.

This is slightly complicated by the fact that there can also be multiple root nodes. It an item does not have a parentID, it is a root node.

Example array (datetime and other info omitted):

```
Array
(
    [0] => MyObject
        (
            [id:protected] => 1
            [parentID:protected] => 2
        )

    [1] => MyObject
        (
            [id:protected] => 4
        )

    [2] => MyObject
        (
            [id:protected] => 2
            [parentID:protected] => 4
        )

    [3] => MyObject
        (
            [id:protected] => 3
        )

    [4] => MyObject
        (
        [id:protected] => 5
        [parentID:protected] => 3
    )
)
```

I would like to find an efficient way to remove all items that are invalid according to the first paragraph, and return an array of the remaining items.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient thing to do is to just loop through all the items and remove the nodes who are self expired. By doing this, when you later construct the tree(I assume eventually you will), any items that didn't manually get removed by the self expired criteria, will be orphaned because an ancestor is missing, and that covers the ancestor expired criteria. You could reconvert the tree back to flat if needed, but I'm guessing you want the tree eventually.

Comment: I actually don't want a tree in the end, I would like to return an array of the remaining items. If it is efficient to make a tree to do the pruning that's one thing, but I need to make it an array at the end.

Comment: Its going to be very close to optimum. You don't *need* to build the tree, but, your tree building algo already does what needs to be done after you remove self expired nodes - make sure remaining nodes still have a path to a root node. I'm assuming there's no other data stored in the object that could improve the ability to quickly locate ancestors, for example, "an ancestors id is always less than the ids of its descendants" or other stuff that could be used to tailor an algo.